# Wget always downloading index.html?

Tags: firefox, downloads, file-sharing, wget, webapps

I am using the following command:

`wget -r -p --page-requisites robots=off -U mozilla https://opig.stats.ox.ac.uk/webapps/sabdab-sabpred/sabdab/archive/all/`

to download a file called `all_structures.zip`, I have also tried:
`wget -r -p --page-requisites robots=off -U mozilla https://opig.stats.ox.ac.uk/webapps/sabdab-sabpred/sabdab/archive/all/all_structures.zip`

In the first case, an `index.html` file is downloaded, the html file looks to be the same size as the file I need.

I have also tried using the `reject` parameter to exclude html files, but then it just downloads a file called `index.html.tmp`.

In the second case, the wget command errors out, claiming the file cannot be found.

If you visit the link in a browser, it will initiate a file download.

Not sure what is happening here, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Read `man wget`. There's an option to treat `index.html` as a list of links it should get. I'm not telling you which option, since I regard reading `man` pages as a sacred duty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the website is using a script to start the file download, lets try with `curl` instead of `wget`

```
curl -O -J -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" https://opig.stats.ox.ac.uk/webapps/sabdab-sabpred/sabdab/archive/all/all_structures.zip
```

If that still dont work maybe the website require some specific event like accepting cookies, or javascript.